# Project list is not displayed in project tab

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have uploaded project from my local drive to GitHub which is only displayed in the repository but project board is empty.
There is not any list is shown over there.

How can I overcome this problem?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5u1s.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do have the same for [my own project](https://github.com/VonC/b2d)

By default, there is no project board data associated to a project.
See "[About project boards](https://help.github.com/articles/about-project-boards/)"

> Project board cards contain relevant metadata for issues and pull requests, like labels, assignees, the status, and who opened it.

A new project with no issue or pull request would have an *empty* project board.